# How to build openssl on linux using Conan

Tags: linux, openssl, conan

This seems to be the best way to build openssl from source on Linux.  However, I can not find a way to build it using -fPIC and -shared (since it will be a static file linked).

Version: https://www.conan.io/source/OpenSSL/1.0.2g/lasote/stable

Alternatively, Ive tried to find pre-built binaries but atlas I could not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the latest Conan package recipe [here](https://github.com/lasote/conan-openssl/blob/release/1.0.2l/conanfile.py), the prebuilt packages are in the [conan-center](https://bintray.com/conan/conan-center) repository, conan.io repository is no longer active.

To build the shared flavor of the packages with fPIC:

1. Add the conan-center repository to the remotes:

   `conan remote add conan-center https://api.bintray.com/conan/conan/conan-center`
2. Specify the latest version reference in your requirements (your conanfile.txt for example), specifying the shared option:

```
[requires]
OpenSSL/1.0.2l@conan/stable
[options]
OpenSSL:shared=True
```

3. Install it. If you get an error because you don't find prebuilt binaries you can build from sources with `--build missing` parameter

`conan install`

You can also build it in Windows with VisualStudio, MinGW, OSX with apple-clang, Linux with gcc... Exactly the same procedure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, how do you also build debug and release versions? -s build_type="Release/Debug" but add this on the conan install?

Comment: Yes. You can also use profiles (text file with settings, options...etc) and pass a profile with --profile path/to/profile